# Display notification when the question you are answering is voted as dupe

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, notifications, user-interface, duplicate-questions

It'll be nice if a notification is displayed when you're writing an answer to a question and someone else votes it as a dupe. Today, I answered a question and when I submitted, I noticed that it's being voted as an exact duplicate. It was indeed a duplicate so I deleted my answer and voted as a dupe. It would be nice to have notifications like the one that says "2 new answers added to the question" for duplicate votes and closing too.

Comment: aaah, delete. (1) You've earned the 'Peer Pressure' badge... AH

Comment: didn't know about the Disciplined badge... was an unliked question :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agreed. If we're embracing the Fastest Gun in the West, this can certainly be aggravating. I know I always answer the question as fast as I can unless I know that I've seen the question before--I'm not actively checking for dupes. So a little, "Hey, you're wasting your time" banner would be fantastic. Especially because I'm verbose and I like to write a treatise on the most mundane of topics.

Comment: Heh. Agreed. Searching for dupes would usually take longer than just typing an answer if you haven't seen it before and know the actual wording. Even if it's later marked as a dupe and you delete your answer, you haven't lost too much in comparison :)

Comment: My treatises are more treatisier than your treatises

Answer (score 0):

I like this idea... not deleting the question is ok (as Jeff stated, this serves the purpose of incrementing the chances of finding a question when you search with different words), but all the answers should be in the original.

That way if you find a question with no answers, you can click on the **possible duplicates** link and find them all in one place