# Vote to close (dup) notification

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display notification when the question you are answering is voted as dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15663/display-notification-when-the-question-you-are-answering-is-voted-as-dupe)

When answering a question, we get notified (via the handy banner on top) when someone else has provided an answer.  This can save time and allow us to abort an attempt if another better answer already exists.  It seems like it would also be useful if we are notified when someone has voted to close the bug as a dup, as that is essentially the same thing as the original use-case -- a better answer already exists, so stop bothering with yours.  Is this feature request reasonable?

Comment: it only means that the *question* already exists (probably) -- your answer might still come in handy :)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15663/display-notification-when-the-question-you-are-answering-is-voted-as-dupe). A related request is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40316/add-an-alert-when-answering-a-question-that-has-at-least-a-close-vote-as-duplicat), and something implemented which was a step forward for this is [this feature here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate).

Comment: Sorry for the dup.  I *did* try to search. :(